# How can I convert a tag to being a synonym?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

For example, there are 3 tags on Stack Overflow:

- [xacml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xacml)
- [xacml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xacml2)
- [xacml3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xacml3)

How can I merge all 3? It is not interesting to have different versions. I would like to keep xacml and have the others as synonyms. Is that possible?

### EDIT - Version synonyms

I cannot follow the instructions in the answer to the duplicate question. See below...

[image: version synonym]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms

Comment: It didn't work in my case - see the edit

Comment: That's the wrong way round, that would make xacml a synonym of xacml2

Comment: I tried either way :-)

Comment: You could create a question on the Stack Overflow's Meta where others could vote on this. If it gets enough votes the moderators will create the synonym for you. Alternatively you could try flagging a post with a custom flag to get a moderator to create the synonym, explaining why they should do that but you might find they say they aren't subject matter experts on these tags and suggest the meta question route.